# Problem compiling VS8 C++ program with boost signals

Tags: c++, boost, signals

So I am wanting to use boost signals in my C++ program.

I add:

```
#include <boost/signal.hpp>
```

But I get this error when I build.

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_signals-vc90-mt-gd-1_42.lib'
```

The lib file is not contained within my boost directory.

Typing 'libboost_signal' (with variations) into google hasn't helped.

Anyone encountered this problem before?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

most of Boost is header-file-only source, so you just need to `#include <boost/whatever.hpp>` and your done. However, there's a few sections that require a dll - examples are date/time, regex and signals.

So yuo need to build the signals dll. [instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) are on the boost website and are easy - so easy I've forgotten how I did it last time. (check out section 5.2 on the site).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the boost/stage directory to your linker path in Project Settings. That's where all the boost libraries are. This assumes that you've done the boostrapping/building, of course...

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have done that.

The problem is that the lib doesn't seem to be included with this boost release.  There are plenty of libboost_xyz and boost_xyz.  No libboost_signals.

Why would it even ask for a lib that doesn't seem to exist.